# ko.computed only it works on the last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

This is my HTML:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Full Name:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: person">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name"/></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: lastname"/></td>
            <td data-bind="text: fullname"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
function newPerson(){
    self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.lastname = ko.observable();
    self.fullname = ko.computed(function(){
      var name_full = self.name() + " " +self.lastname();
      return name_full;
    });
}

function personsViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.person = ko.observableArray([
        new newPerson(),
        new newPerson()
    ]);
}

$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new personsViewModel());
})
```

Apparently my is code without any problems, but when you run the script, the event serves only the last row; that is, the second row only serves to generate the event fullname for *all* of the rows.

The `ko.computed` event only serves to the last row the other rows do not take the event.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `var`, or `self` will end up in global scope being overwritten every time you execute `newPerson`.

```js
function newPerson(){
    var self = this; // <=== change is here
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.lastname = ko.observable();
    self.fullname = ko.computed(function(){
      var name_full = self.name() + " " +self.lastname();
      return name_full;
    });
}

function personsViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.person = ko.observableArray([
        new newPerson(),
        new newPerson()
    ]);
}

$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new personsViewModel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Full Name:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: person">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name"/></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: lastname"/></td>
            <td data-bind="text: fullname"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I recommend looking into using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) in your files, as well as a javascript linter like [jshint](http://jshint.com/) in your build setup, as I think both would catch the type of problem you had.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I am learning the new library and forget to put the var! :D

Comment: This hasn't got much to do with KO, it's basic Javascript closures / syntax ;-)